# How to use React.useMemo in custom hook react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook for handling image inputs but I'm trying to encapsulate it with useMemo but I don't know exactly how to do this.

useImage.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useImage = (initialValue) => {
    const [ image, setImage ] = useState(initialValue);
  console.log('useImage');
    return {
        image,
        setImage,
        resetImage: () => setImage({ blob: '', file: null }),
        bindImage: {
            image,
            onChange: (event) => {
                event.persist();
                const imageUrl = event.target.files.length ? URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]) : '';

                if (event.target && imageUrl) {
                    setImage((image) => ({
                        ...image,
                        blob: imageUrl,
                        file: event.target.files[0]
                    }));
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: why do u want to use useMemo

Comment: The `useMemo` would have `image` as a dependency, which makes it pretty useless since anyway the object changes on `image` change, why would you use `useMemo` here?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?, as you can't put Hooks inside a useMemo, it makes no sense anyway.  And would break, as hooks need to be kept in order, and if useMemo did work this is going to break that.

Comment: I use this hook in my form to handling image inputs and whenever my form rerenders then this hook is also triggered so I wanted to run this hook only for image input change event